# android app crashes at restart

Tags: java, android, crash

while launching app it gives java null point error in following methods

```
 private ParamHandler(Context context) {
      Log.e("ParamHandler : Constructor : Enter"); 
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        mTm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        mCm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        mVersionedPsc = VersionedPsc.getInstance(mTm);
        msisdn = getPhoneNumber();
        Log.e("ParamHandler : Constructor : Exit"); 
    }

    public static synchronized ParamHandler getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new ParamHandler(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
}
```

this my logcat file.in this line number 45 and 55  gives null point error

```
03-20 07:07:10.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1240): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-83
03-20 07:07:10.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1240): Process: com.instantmeter.starter, PID: 1240
03-20 07:07:10.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1240): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 07:07:10.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1240):     at com.mobile.instantmeter.service.ParamHandler.<init>(ParamHandler.java:45)
03-20 07:07:10.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1240):     at com.mobile.instantmeter.service.ParamHandler.getInstance(ParamHandler.java:55)
03-20 07:07:10.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1240):     at com.mobile.instantmeter.service.MasterThread.run(MasterThread.java:110)
03-20 07:07:10.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1240):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: What line? The stack trace provides you with a line number, find that line.

Comment: mContext = context.getApplicationContext();  line number 45 and 55

Comment: Y U NO LOG MON? Assign to the context what you receive as a context from the parameters. `mContext = context`

Comment: This `mContext = context.getApplicationContext();` should be `mContext = getApplicationContext();`

Answer (score 1):

be sure to send/receive the `context` in `ParamHandler(Context context)` method, probably `context` is null. then you don´t need set the mContext variable with the application context.

```
 private ParamHandler(Context context) {
      Log.e("ParamHandler : Constructor : Enter"); 
       //mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        mTm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        mCm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        mVersionedPsc = VersionedPsc.getInstance(mTm);
        msisdn = getPhoneNumber();
        Log.e("ParamHandler : Constructor : Exit"); 
    }
```

other option using the `mContext` variable containing the application context.

```
private Context mContext;

  private ParamHandler() {
       Log.e("ParamHandler : Constructor : Enter"); 
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        mTm = (TelephonyManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        mCm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        mVersionedPsc = VersionedPsc.getInstance(mTm);
        msisdn = getPhoneNumber();
        Log.e("ParamHandler : Constructor : Exit"); 
    }
```

Comment: this method works fine in normal launch.but i m using autostart function after boot.maybe it could be the problem.yours suggestion are not working

Comment: it´s not a good practice to use context and mContext variables in the same method, just be sure to send the context in getInstance(CONTEXT) method. :)